# The POST method is not supported for this route. (Laravel with ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to check the availability of time and place for reserving event room, using laravel and ajax.

I've tried all possible solutions found on the web. But still not working. Please help.

I've a form whose method is `POST`. And I don't forget to add `@csrf` to it. In the form, I have 3 input fields which is normal. Below is my code.

```html
<form id="check-form" method="post">
@csrf
   <input type="text" name="place" id="room_no">
   <input type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time">
   <input type="text" name="end_time" id="end_time">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
$('#check-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('I'm still ok till here.');

    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
        url: "check",
    data: {
        'place': $('#room_no').val(),
        'start_time': $('#start_time').val(),
        'end_time': $('#start_time').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('iam here -> ' + data);
        }
        console.log('ohooh');
    });
});
```

In my web.php,

```php
Route::post('check', 'MyController@check');
```

The problem is . . .

> **The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   GET, HEAD.**

It doesn't seem to follow along the route.
Thank you.

edited:
As answers say, I've edited like below. But doesn't seem working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/** this does not also work for me. ;-(
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
}); */

$('#check-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('I'm still ok till here.');

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: "check",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: {
        'place': $('#room_no').val(),
        'start_time': $('#start_time').val(),
        'end_time': $('#start_time').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('iam here -> ' + data);
        }
        console.log('ohooh');
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check if there are other routes with the same url? maybe you have a Route::get('check', 'Whatever');

Comment: No Rabi. It's only one there.

Comment: You're using a relative path, are you certain it's targeting where you expect? Check the console to ensure the generated absolute URL is correct. Also note that your `console.log()` has a syntax error which will be causing issues, although I assume that's only in the question as your AJAX request wouldn't even be sent, otherwise.

Comment: Try giving the route a name Route::post('check', 'MyController@check')->name('checkForm'); then in the ajax use the url helper: url: {{ route('checkForm') }}

Comment: It's doesn't work Rabi. I've tried it.

Comment: Change Method to Type in the Ajax method. I would also add $.ajaxSetup({headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')} }); in you document ready section.

Comment: try adding a leading `/` in the url at the ajax call. if for example you are at `example.com/page/subpage`, when `url='check'` it will lead to `example.com/page/check` instead of `example.com/check`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify csrf token in script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(".check-form").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/check',
       data: {
          'place': $('#room_no').val(),
          'start_time': $('#start_time').val(),
          'end_time': $('#start_time').val()
       },
       success:function(data){
          alert(data.success);
       }
    });
});
```

or

```
  $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/ajax',
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      success:function(data){}
   });
```

Comment: With an ajax call, the form data is passed on to the POST route with the ‘data’ attribute @Htet does not pass the CSRF token. This answer should fix his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change ajax request code like this.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
        url: "check",
    data: {
        'place': $('#room_no').val(),
        'start_time': $('#start_time').val(),
        'end_time': $('#start_time').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('iam here -> ' + data);
        }
        console.log('ohooh');
    });
```

I've replaced request attribute method to type

Comment: Method or Type should not make a difference. I believe it has something to do with the CSRF token that he's not passing on in his ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JavaScript code has some typos. The `POST` route you defined is correct, but if you check the network tab of Developer Tools, you'll see that the code tries to `POST` on the current route (which implicit is a `GET/HEAD` only, I suppose).

The first typo or mistake is on line 4 of your code:

```js
// unescaped single quote inside single quotes, or wrap the text in double quotes
console.log('I'm still ok till here.');
         // ^-^---------------------^
console.log("I'm still ok till here.");
console.log('I\'m still ok till here.');
```

The second is on line 16, where you close a bracket ending the `success(data)` function early, combined with code on line 17 results in an error.

All you need to do is fix the first `console.log`, and move the second inside the `success` call.

You can see the code in action here https://jsfiddle.net/c54vuemn/.

```js
$('#check-form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "check",
    data: {
      'place': $('#room_no').val(),
      'start_time': $('#start_time').val(),
      'end_time': $('#start_time').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('iam here -> ' + data);
      console.log('ohooh');
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

I recommend using an editor, plugin, or IDE that at least highlights warnings/errors, typos happen to all of us and are usually a pain to debug.

Comment: WOOO... When I move last console.log('ohooh') into the success function, it response my data. Seems to be working. Thank you. But In my MyController@check, I diedump dd('i reach here'). It doesn't come out.